# Vb .net unmanaged dll и все все все

Tags: c++

Есть dll для работы с протоколом j2534 из пакета open port2.0, есть работающий сэмпл для неё на цпп, есть проект на вб дот нет.
Вопрос: как передать структуры на вб дот нет если в исходном  сэмпле вызов функции организован так :
passthruioctl(unsigned long devid, unsigned long ioctl, const void *pInput, void *pOut)

?

Ps маршалить через неуправляемые куски памяти пробовал, крашится по защите записи

Comment: Приведите пример того, как пробовали. Если падает, значит не совсем правильно реализована передача `managed` <-> `unmanaged`.

Comment: добавил код  в ответе самому себе

Comment: @DowJhob не надо так делать. Дописывайте части вопроса прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

правильно так:

```
  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> Public Structure inbuf
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public length As UInt32
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public svcid As UInt32
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)> Public infosvcid As UInt16
End Structure
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)> Public Structure outbuf
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public length As UInt32
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=256)> Public data() As Byte
End Structure
```

маршалить структуры, в обертке указывать их byref

```
Public Declare Function serialNum Lib "op20pt32.dll" Alias "PassThruIoctl" (ByVal ChannelID As UInt32, ByVal IoctlID As UInt32, ByRef pInput As inbuf, ByRef pOutput As outbuf) As Integer
```

и вызов так:

```
serialNum(DevID, TX_IOCTL_APP_SERVICE, inbuf1, outbuf1)
```